# The name "webBrowser" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
    {
        WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser.Visible = false;
        webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        webBrowser.Navigate("want to keep it private.");
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
    }
}

public void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElement botNick = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("nick");
    botNick.SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);

    HtmlElement botPlay = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")[2];
    botPlay.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

Why am i getting "The name "webBrowser" does not exist in the current context"?

Comment: it is scoped to the `button1_Click` event handler.

Comment: What makes you think that a local variable defined in one function would be available in another function?

Comment: @Marc B what could i do?

Comment: @Aarivex, the `sender` argument of the event handler contains the object which fired the event -- for the *DocumentCompleted* event this would be the *WebBrowser* object which in all likelihood you want to work with in the *webBrowser_DocumentCompleted* method...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, "The name "webBrowser" does not appear in the current context" error means that you propably have not defined such a variable/field/property/etc. in the current context.

Secondly, since you have not clarified the line of the error, I will assume that it appeared on these 2 lines:

```
HtmlElement botNick = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("nick");
HtmlElement botPlay = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")[2];
```

This happens because, while you have declared `webBrowser` here:

```
WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
```

which exists in function `void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`
and therefore is invisible to the function `void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)`.
To rectify this situation you can either pass the webBrowser as an argument, or define a new var with the name of webBrowser in the latter function.